# Program to calculate the number of votes towards a political party, and then arrange them in alphabetical order

Tags: python-3.x

I have a small problem with a program I am currently working on. In this program I prompt the user to enter the name of the political party/parties they want to vote for. After this I count the number of votes to each party and then arrange the number of votes towards to party/parties in alphabetical order, according to the name of the political parties. Here is my program:

```
print("Independent Electoral Commission\n--------------------------------")

votes = []

#User is prompted to enter the political party/parties they want to vote for
vote = input("Enter the names of parties (terminated by DONE):\n")
while vote != 'DONE':
    votes.append(vote) # This appends/adds the vote(s) the user types in, to votes
    vote = input("")

counters={}

# This calculates the total number of votes towards a certain political party
for vote in votes:
    if not vote in counters:
        counters[vote]=0
    counters[vote] += 1

print("\n""Vote counts:")
for vote in counters:
    print(vote + ' '*(10 - len(vote)) ,'-',counters[vote])
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
Independent Electoral Commission
--------------------------------
Enter the names of parties (terminated by DONE):
DAL
ACNO
OPT
DAL
DAL
PRQ
DAL
DONE

Vote counts:
ACNO       - 1
DAL        - 4
OPT        - 1
PRQ        - 1
```

Instead I get this:

```
Independent Electoral Commission
--------------------------------
Enter the names of parties (terminated by DONE):
DAL
ACNO
OPT
DAL
DAL
PRQ
DAL
DONE

Vote counts:
PRQ        - 1
DAL        - 4
ACNO       - 1
OPT        - 1
```

Comment: `dict`s are not ordered. If you want to print in order, explicitly sort the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort the keys after you calculate the total number of votes for a party:

```
sorted_parties = sorted(counters.keys())
```

Then, print it out as:

```
print("\n""Vote counts:")
for vote in sorted_parties:
    print(vote + ' '*(10 - len(vote)) ,'-',counters[vote])
```